# Read more/read less issue (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    // The height of the content block when it's not expanded
    var adjustheight = 130;
    // The "more" link text
    var moreText = "Click to read more...";
    // The "less" link text
    var lessText = "Click to read less...";
    // Sets the .more-block div to the specified height and hides any content that overflows
    $(".more-less .more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
    // The section added to the bottom of the "more-less" div
    $(".more-less").append('<p style="display:block;margin-top:8px"><a href="#" class="adjust"></a></p>');
    $("a.adjust").text(moreText);
    $(".adjust").toggle(function() {
            $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', 'auto').css('overflow', 'visible');
            // Hide the [...] when expanded
            $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'none');
            $(this).text(lessText);
        }, function() {
            $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
            $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'block');
            $(this).text(moreText);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tqwdh/1/

it always has "Click here to read more..."

even if the field is shorter than the value of 130

how can i make the Click here to read more... appear only when the div contents exceed the max value?

Comment: means if there are less chars. then u dont want any Read more,Read Less

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5ExDQ/2/ ?

Comment: @uuser3558931 !? what do you mean that this is a MooTools question and not jQuery?! Could you explain that?

Comment: You probably want to use `.closest()` instead of `.parents()`.

Comment: I think instead of height of div you should use length of string in your div for see more & see less.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to measure actual height of your div container and depending on it you can toggle what ever you want. I can't get your point exactly. Anyway try this

```
    if( $(".more-block").height() > 130 )
    {
        $(".adjust").text(moreText);
       //other logics
    }
    else
    {
            $(".adjust").text(lessText);
           //other logics
    }
```

Comment: this looks like it's what i might need, where should i put this exactly?